# How to insert multiple rows in SQLite, partly from other tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I have to do some sstuff in SQLite, but since I am no expert in SQL at all, it is pretty hard for me.

I have to fill the following Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "tiki_user_preferences" (
    "user"  TEXT,
    "prefName"  TEXT,
    "value" TEXT
)
```

with something like this:

```
peter|realName|Peter Pan
peter|user_information|private
peter|mailCharset|utf8
max|realName|Max Mustermann
max|user_information|private
max|mailCharset|utf8
petra|realName|Petra Klein
petra|user_information|private
petra|mailCharset|utf8
```

I have another table users_users where "user" is stored as "login" per row,
like this:

```
login|email|lastLogin
==========================
peter|peter@domain.tld|3543534
max|max@domain.tld|543541
petra|petra@domain.tld|654641
```

"prefName" and "value" shall be the same for every "user", except for prefName='realName'. The Value for realName comes from table session_attribute, where name='name':

```
sid|name|value
=============================
peter|name|Peter Pan
peter|wiki_editrows|5
peter|rubish|söofiglsijs
max|name|Max Mustermann
max|wiki_editrows|8
max|rubish|söofiglsijs
petra|name|Petra Klein
petra|wiki_editrows|10
ptera|rubish|söofiglsijs
```

So far, I have tried this

```
INSERT INTO tiki_user_preferences VALUES
((SELECT login 
  FROM users_users 
  AS 'user'), 'user_information','private'),
((SELECT login 
  FROM users_users 
  AS 'user'), 'mailCharset','utf8'),
((SELECT login 
  FROM users_users 
  AS 'user'), 'realName',(SELECT value 
                          FROM session_attribute 
                          WHERE name='name' AND 
                                session_attribute.sid=tiki_user_preferences.user));
```

At first: this does not work. The first two datasets do work partly, the third doesn't at all.

For the first two: only two rows are built, not for every "login" in the table users_users.

For the last one: it says:

```
no such column: tiki_user_preferences.user
```

I hope someone out there can help me...

Comment: What about existing data? Or are you replacing the table tiki_user_preferences

Comment: You can use a select query as source for your insert. Look up the syntax

Comment: well, I am trying to move from Trac to Tikiwiki. For that, I have to transfer the accountinformations of Trac to Tikiwiki. If you look at this thread, that is one part of doing so..

I know that there is a select query for the insert. But I dont know how this could be helpful for my task? If you know a specific solution, maybe you could share it with me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found this, rather unelegant, solution:

```
INSERT INTO tiki_user_preferences (user)
SELECT login FROM users_users;
UPDATE tiki_user_preferences
SET prefName='realName';
UPDATE tiki_user_preferences
SET value=(SELECT value
           FROM session_attribute
           WHERE name='name' AND
                 tiki_user_preferences.user=session_attribute.sid);

INSERT INTO tiki_user_preferences (user)
SELECT login FROM users_users;
UPDATE tiki_user_preferences
SET prefName='user_information',
    value='private'
WHERE prefName is NULL;

INSERT INTO tiki_user_preferences (user)
SELECT login FROM users_users;
UPDATE tiki_user_preferences
SET prefName='mailCharset',
    value='utf8'
WHERE prefName is NULL;
```

It works for my purpose, the main disadvantage is that the output is not ordered by user, but I think I have to live with that.

Edit: If you work with a temporary table, you can order it:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp.a;
CREATE TABLE temp.a (
    "user"  TEXT,
    "prefName"  TEXT,
    "value" TEXT
);
INSERT INTO temp.a (user)
SELECT login FROM users_users;
UPDATE temp.a
SET prefName='realName';
UPDATE temp.a
SET value=(SELECT value
           FROM session_attribute
           WHERE name='name' AND
                 temp.a.user=session_attribute.sid);

INSERT INTO temp.a (user)
SELECT login FROM users_users;
UPDATE temp.a
SET prefName='user_information',
    value='private'
WHERE prefName is NULL;

INSERT INTO temp.a (user)
SELECT login FROM users_users;
UPDATE temp.a
SET prefName='mailCharset',
    value='utf8'
WHERE prefName is NULL;

INSERT INTO tiki_user_preferences (user,prefName,value)
SELECT user,prefName,value
FROM temp.a
ORDER BY user ASC;

DROP TABLE temp.a;
```